# References about positivism

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, foundations

To found the current set theory, it has been necessary to remove some paradoxes like the well-known Russel paradox. It was thus necessary to clarify why things like $$\{x : x \notin x\}$$ can't reasonably be considered as sets. Several propositions were made like our usual ZFC with a limitation of the size but another was the "positivism paradigm". I know that the global idea of this theory is to treat separately the two symbols $\notin$ and $\in$ and to state that one can't refer negatively to itself but I can't find after many research **a good purely mathematical text** which is quite exhaustive about this subject. Many philosophical texts can be found but I wan't the pure mathematical approach with rigourous definitions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I never heard on something like that. At best, Quine's New Foundations disallow $x\notin x$ in the comprehension schema, as it is not stratified.

Comment: "Purely mathematical?" AFAICT mathematicians don't generally care about such things.

Comment: Isn't there something called positive set theory?

Comment: I didn't know this thesis from Isaac Malitz, but I know about Quine and I'm sure it is nothing to do with positivism. And the thesis of Malitz is too recent, I speak about something developped at the beginning of the 20th. It has started with philosophical considerations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) and some formal mathematics were produced, but I can't find them.

Comment: May you give a reference to some of the "many philosophical texts" ?

Comment: Do you know [*Models for a paraconsistent set theory*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jal.2004.07.010) by Thierry Libert?